# Temporarily restrict access to IIS website

Tags: iis-8

We have a site (asp.net on IIS) that implements forms authentication.  Some sections of the site are locked down and require registration, some are open to the public.

This site is actively under development and we need to temporarily restrict access to this entire site, only permitting access to the development team, but without altering the underlying forms authentication mechanism.

Is the a way we can do this within IIS without altering the web.config of the site?

Comment: Stop IIS. Restart it when you're done.

Comment: @joeqwerty - apologies, didn't make that very clear at all.  Still need access to the site, but only for  limited set of people.

Comment: How about setting the bindings on the site to an obscure port, and only notify your dev team of the new port assignment.